# window.open blocked by default (popups blocked)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have share link for my site and had following code:

```
function handleFacebook(shortURL) {
  $(".facebook").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      window.open(
        'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(shortURL),
        'facebook-share-dialog',
        'width=626,height=436');
      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

html (JADE)

```
  div.facebook
    img(src="/images/facebook_logo.png")
```

However, this does not work when popups are blocked.

How can I get around popup blocked issue???

Not sure how to fix and where/what to add??

Comment: Try addthis site share. check this link https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.Ukz19Kr7sYw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to added many share links right ? and because the browser will blocked popup if you not include `window.open` in link `href`.

So you have to create entire of link with `window.open` in its `href` like this one.

Example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/EgBQK/)

```
var url = ['http://google.com', 'http://bing.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com/'];

$.each(url, function(i, val){

    $('body').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=\'+encodeURIComponent(\''+val+'\'), \'facebook-share-dialog\', \'width=626,height=436\'); return false;"> Share on Facebook </a></div>');

});
```

Comment: I updated my code above. I did use that as a reference. Was not sure how to incorporate <a> tag in jQuery

Comment: You just add this as HTML (not in js file). and just define shortUrl (in js) before this code appears.

Comment: I could not make this work. My issue is that I may need to create many shortURLs in javascript depending on logic. Just setting shortURL before the code appears may not be enough...I may need to to generate a different URL after code appears....I wanted to do this purely in jQuery (no inline HTML code)....but I am not able to get past window.open (...) blocked issue in chrome??....Please provide ideas????

Comment: I just edit the answer to suit your case. please take a look.