# jquery code Inline onlick code for window,open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling with this for some time and hope to get experts help me.

Context is:

[window.open blocked by default (popups blocked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150779/window-open-blocked-by-default-popups-blocked)

I was provided with an answer in comment 1 in that question the fiddle is as below

http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/EgBQK/

This might be the answer but I am failing to understand that:

Can not this be done purely in jQuery? I am talking abt following code:

```
   $('body').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=\'+encodeURIComponent(\''+val+'\'), \'facebook-share-dialog\', \'width=626,height=436\'); return false;"> Share on Facebook </a></div>');
```

How can I convert this code to pure jQuery? **In the code above, html code is created in jquery code?????**

Comment: If you are thinking jquery without javascript, then there is no pure jquery.. :)

Comment: no I meant jQuery/javascript...I meant HTML code is created in jQuery/js code....that is an issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var url = ['http://google.com', 'http://bing.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com/'],
    $coll;

$coll = $.map(url, function (val) {
    return $('<div/>').append($('<a/>', {
        href: '#',
        rel: val,
        text: 'Share on Facebook'
    }).click(handleClick));
});
$('body').append($coll);

function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(this.rel), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436');
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gk2em/)**

Comment: this looks like might be what I was looking for.....let me try this

Comment: can I change "rel" later in TIME....I may not have URL array upfront....it gets build with time based on events....on an event, I want to have difffern value for rel....I need to try that...thanks a lot

Comment: @user2384694 Yes you can always change it when you need it to be changes.

Comment: @user2384694 updated the answer, use $.map rather than $.each.